# Picker error "Specified cast is not valid" when getting the SelectedItem value in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, picker, selecteditem

I have a picker, already set with the bindings, but when I'm trying to copy the selecteditem value to a variable but shows error "System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid'. The info contained in the selected item is actually correct, this is my code:

```
IDPisteroMainPage = Convert.ToInt32(pck_Pisteros.SelectedItem);
```

also tried this (didn't work either, different error thrown tho):

```
IDPisteroMainPage = Convert.ToInt32(pck_Pisteros.SelectedItem as Pisteros);
```

Pisteros being the model in used.

Error:

[image: Error]

Also I have the binding for the same object on SelectedIndex, but this one still returns the index and not the PisteroID which is what I need, but if I use the following:

```
IDPisteroMainPage = Convert.ToInt32(pck_Pisteros.SelectedIndex);
```

the value does gets copied to the variable without issues

Comment: `SelectedItem` != `SelectedIndex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you actually want or the types involved. However, it could be you are looking for.

```
IDPisteroMainPage = Convert.ToInt32(((Pisteros)pck_Pisteros.SelectedItem).PisteroId);

// or slightly more fault tolerant if you expect a null 
if(pck_Pisteros.SelectedItem is Pisteros pisteros)
   IDPisteroMainPage = pisteros.PisteroId;
else
   // handle null (if need be)
   

// or if PisteroId is an int and SelectedItem is never null
IDPisteroMainPage = ((Pisteros)pck_Pisteros.SelectedItem).PisteroId
```